# Batch script to move files that contain certain string

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-rename

Hi guys just got the following code script running to search in a directory for files that contain the string "ABC" and move them to the directory at the end.

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b^|find "ABC"') do move /Y "%%F"  "C:\DESTINATION_DIRECTORY"
```

Was wondering how to modify this to not have to be run from the input directory, i.e to add a *SOURCE_DIRECTORY* variable so I can run this script from elsewhere but have it parse thru the *SOURCE_DIRECTORY*.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off

set "root=c:\st"
pushd %root% && (
    for  %%# in ("*ABC*") do echo move /Y "%%~f#"  "C:\DESTINATION_DIRECTORY"
)
popd
```

or

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('dir /b "%root%\*ABC*"') do echo move /Y "%root%\%%~nx#"  "C:\DESTINATION_DIRECTORY"
```

for recursive search:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('dir /b /s "%root%\*ABC*"') do echo move /Y "%%~f#"  "C:\DESTINATION_DIRECTORY"
```